# Classic ASP. Where a user is coming from?

Tags: asp-classic

One certain page of my mobile website, I want to it so that when the users come to a certain page with a form on it part of the form will be filled out for them depending on what page they came from. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Referer` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer).
However, you cannot rely on this header to exist or be correct.

Instead, you can put a parameter in the query string in each of the source pages.

Comment: How exactly do I add a query string? (sorry I very new at all of this)

Comment: On the page they are coming from (call it bob.asp), the link to the form page looks like www.yoursite.com/formpage.asp?camefrom=bob (or whatever you want to name your variable) On the form page, you look at request.querystring("camefrom"), find bob and act accordingly with whatever you want to preload.

Answer (score 2):

```
Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")
```

Comment: This should have been the answer.